# Google Maps Pro Plan not available in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps-api-3

How to grant access to Google maps in Cordova on Android. I have individual api_key
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=gme-API_KEY&v=3.exp

In panel on the force.com I must add the address from which the application can access, eg.

- file:///asset/www/index.html
- file://asset/www/index.html
- file:/asset/www/index.html

whether it is done in a different way?